# Java class name convention with respect to managed been usage in Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, managed-bean

I am using Eclipse Indigo and whenever I create a new class starting with lower case then a warning is shown as displayed below (" Type name is discouraged. By convention, Java type names usually start with an uppercase letter").

[image]

Now in my xHTML / JSF file, if i try to access the class with first letter in caps then it is not accessible e-g;

'#{MyClass.variableName}'       is NOT accessible nor the class constructor is called
whereas 
'#{myClass.variableName}'       works fine.

Note: class has an annotation "@ManagedBean"

Thanks

This is edited part:
It only works if class is created with first letter as lower case "myClass" and in JSF file access with the same lower case "myClass"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to follow the Java standard for class name I have used the following approach.

```
@ManagedBean(name="myClass")
public class MyClass {

}
```

previously due to JSF behaviour, I was using

```
@ManagedBean
public class myClass {

}
```

Please also share that what you do in such cases.

Thanks,

Asad

Answer (score 1):

Its the expected behavior

> By default, the name associated with a bean is simply the lowercase form of its class name

You give your class a name with Capitalized Letter , like `MyClass` and accessing it from your xhtmls like this `#{myClass.someVariable}` (with a lower case prefix)

its not related to Primefaces , its the general approach in JSF

Comment: It only works if class is created with first letter as lower case "myClass" and in JSF file access with the same lower case "myClass"

Comment: you should create MyClass java file and access it as myClass in xhtml

Comment: used the following @ManagedBean(name="myClass")
public class MyClass {
} instead of @ManagedBean
public class myClass {

}