# Primefaces Schedule - Extracting data from event

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

After a day of pain I finally got data into the schedule event.

I'm now trying to set event when it's clicked, it loads a new page using the data variable.

Here's the xhtml

```xml
<p:schedule id="schedule" 
    value="#{LeadListScheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="schedule">  
    <p:ajax event="eventSelect"  
        listener="#{LeadListController.redirectToLeadEdit(Data)}" /> 
</p:schedule>
```

And the Java

```
public void redirectToLeadEdit(String data) throws IOException {
    redirect("/lead/" + data + "/edit");
}
```

How can I get the data object that's now in the event so the url works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [showcase explains](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf), there's no need of manually passing the current selected event as an argument to the listener method. Just declare a method where you catch the incoming event and get the data from it. After that, you can call your redirect method with everything you need.

```xml
<p:ajax event="eventSelect"  
        listener="#{LeadListController.onEventSelect}" />
```

```java
public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {  
    ScheduleEvent event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();  
    redirect(event.getData());
}
```

Appart from that and totally unrelated to the problem, I encourage you to name your managed beans as the bean class name with the first letter lowercased. It's a java specification that has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297006/java-class-name-convention-with-respect-to-managed-been-usage-in-primefaces).

Comment: Great thanks I think that's nearly there. For some reason I'm getting a nullpointexception when accessing the method

       <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{LeadListScheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="schedule">  
         <p:ajax event="eventSelect"  listener="#{LeadListScheduleController.onEventSelect}" /> 
        </p:schedule>

Comment: Nov 27, 2013 9:56:02 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: Method not found: co.beek.web.lead.LeadListScheduleController@dbd48c4.onEventSelect(org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent)
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: co.beek.web.lead.LeadListScheduleController@dbd48c4.onEventSelect(org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent)