# Primefaces Schedule EventSelect - Method Not Found'

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Why isn't my method being found?

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 with Schedule, and after a lot of trouble managed to get some data into the event. I'm now trying to pass the data to an event and got some help in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212101/primefaces-schedule-extracting-data-from-event). Now I can't call the method to try and do something with the data (redirect to a page)

```
<p:schedule value="#{LeadListScheduleController.eventModel}">  
 <p:ajax event="eventSelect"  listener="#{LeadListScheduleController.onEventSelect()}" /> 
 </p:schedule>
```

Java:

```
public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) throws IOException {  
    ScheduleEvent event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();  
    id = (String) event.getData();
    redirect("lead/" + id + "/edit");
}
```

Trace:

```
Nov 27, 2013 11:08:09 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: Method not found: co.beek.web.lead.LeadListScheduleController@6c590384.onEventSelect(org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent)
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: co.beek.web.lead.LeadListScheduleController@6c590384.onEventSelect(org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:155)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:231)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntrySelectEvent.processListener(ScheduleEntrySelectEvent.java:42)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1366)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at co.beek.pano.filters.SessionSharingFilter.doFilter(SessionSharingFilter.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at co.beek.pano.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at co.beek.pano.filters.SessionSharingFilter.doFilter(SessionSharingFilter.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at co.beek.pano.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with update of Primfaces to 3.5